# Progressbar на get запрос

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax, get

Задача сделать progressbar. Есть get-запрос, необходимо ВО ВРЕМЯ его выполнение отображать прогресс( картинку), а после окончания скрывать.
Это запрос:
 `$.get( "http://api-campus-kpi-ua.azurewebsites.net/Rnp/Filters", function( rnpFilters ) {
        populateRnpFilters(rnpFilters);
    });`
Вывод примерно должен быть таким:
    `$('.spinner').style.display = 'block';`
    `$('.spinner').style.display = 'none';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто вот так:

```
$('.spinner').show();

$.get("http://api-campus-kpi-ua.azurewebsites.net/Rnp/Filters",
    function(rnpFilters) {
    populateRnpFilters(rnpFilters);
    $('.spinner').hide();
});
```